# Configure Bitbucket-Webhook for every Repository

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, bitbucket, webhooks

I am currently setting up a CI-Pipeline with Jenkins, Bitbucket, Sonarqube, Maven,...

I want to create templates so that i can easily change the pipeline for different repositories and projects by changing some fields only.

Bitbucket only allows to create a webhook for single repositories so that i have to create a new webhook for every new repository which should be linked to Jenkins.

Is it possible to create a global webhook in Bitbucket ? So that every repository has the same link to my jenkins-server.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a template repository in a template project and add the necessary webhook to it. Add this template repository to the project -> setting -> repository template option. Check the field copy webhooks and save the configuration. Then any repository created inside the project will follow the template have the webhook automatically created. For the existing set of repositories, you have to either manually add the webhook or you can use API calls to BitBucket to add webhooks.